# Python Pandas How to count number of rows that have at least one zero

Tags: python, pandas

I have a data frame in pandas and would like to do some calculations from it.

I think it's more like an intersection kind of problem

Col 1 = [0, 1, 2, 0]
Col 2 = [0, 0 ,1, 0]

Above is my data frame and I would like to count numbers of rows that have at least one 0 in a column.
For example, I expect the output to be 3 since there are 3 rows that have at least a 0.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since `0` is a Falsey value, just use `all`

```
(~df.all(1)).sum()
```

```
3
```

Comment: what does the 1 do in the parentheses?

Comment: Checks along the first axis

Comment: what about the ~ ?

Comment: Negates the mask.  You want rows where *not* all the values are Truthy

Comment: Thanks! you are amazing!

Answer (score 0):

I know this can be done in one line but this example below is to be explicit.

Creating your dataframe

```
df = pd.DataFrame([[0,0],[1,0],[2,1],[0,0]], columns=("Col1","Col2"))
```

`df` looks like

```
   Col1  Col2
0     0     0
1     1     0
2     2     1
3     0     0
```

A simple mask will show you what 'cells' match your filter

```
m = df == 0
```

`m` Looks like

```
    Col1   Col2
0   True   True
1  False   True
2  False  False
3   True   True
```

Using `.any` should show if anything in a series or column etc matches the boolean logic of "any". We ask it to use axis=1 so that it operates row-wise and not column-wise (axis=0)

mrows = m.any(axis=1)

`mrows` looks like

```
0     True
1     True
2    False
3     True
dtype: bool
```

Then you can sum them since a boolean truth is kinda treated like a 1.

```
mrows.sum()    # >>> 3
```

But to be explicit... turn the True's to 1 and False's to 0

```
mrows = mrows[mrows] = 1
mrows.sum()
```